# How to detect unicode characters that are non-normalized?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, rust, normalization, unicode-normalization

Given a UTF-8 string (`&str`), I want to find out any range of characters that are not normalized (e.g. `a\u{300}` instead of `\u{e0}`).

How do I do this?

Edit: Thanks to DK for correcting my faulty UTF-8 sequence. The combining character comes *after* the `a`, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I just realised that the *reason* for the results I was getting is that your example string *is backwards*.  The combining code point should come second, not first.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Well, that depends on the definition of "normalized".

For example:

````rust
/*!
Add this to a `Cargo.toml` manifest:

```cargo
[dependencies]
unicode-normalization = "0.1.1"
```
*/
extern crate unicode_normalization;

fn main() {
    for test_str in vec!["a\u{300}", "\u{e0}"] {
        is_nfd(test_str);
        is_nfkd(test_str);
        is_nfc(test_str);
        is_nfkc(test_str);
    }
}

macro_rules! norm_test {
    ($fn_name:ident, $norm_name:ident) => {
        fn $fn_name(s: &str) {
            use unicode_normalization::UnicodeNormalization;
            println!("is_{}({:?}):", stringify!($norm_name), s);
            let is_norm = s.chars().zip(s.$norm_name())
                .inspect(|&(a, b)| println!(" - ({:x}, {:x})", a as u32, b as u32))
                .all(|(a, b)| a == b);
            println!(" is_norm: {}", is_norm);
        }
    };
}

norm_test! { is_nfd, nfd }
norm_test! { is_nfkd, nfkd }
norm_test! { is_nfc, nfc }
norm_test! { is_nfkc, nfkc }
````

This produces the following output:

```text
is_nfd("a\u{300}"):
 - (61, 61)
 - (300, 300)
 is_norm: true
is_nfkd("a\u{300}"):
 - (61, 61)
 - (300, 300)
 is_norm: true
is_nfc("a\u{300}"):
 - (61, e0)
 is_norm: false
is_nfkc("a\u{300}"):
 - (61, e0)
 is_norm: false
is_nfd("\u{e0}"):
 - (e0, 61)
 is_norm: false
is_nfkd("\u{e0}"):
 - (e0, 61)
 is_norm: false
is_nfc("\u{e0}"):
 - (e0, e0)
 is_norm: true
is_nfkc("\u{e0}"):
 - (e0, e0)
 is_norm: true
```

So `"a\u{300}"` is NFD and NFKD, whilst `"\u{e0}"` is NFC and NFKC.  I don't know of any examples which differ between the K and non-K variants, though the [Unicode FAQ on Normalization](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) will probably explain things better than I can.

Comment: So if I want to detect non-normalized ranges within a string I need to first find ranges of chars where only the first one has `unicode_combining_class` of zero and check those if they are normal (depending on the definition, as you outlined).

Comment: @DK: You can see example of the K forms in http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/ (figure 6, for example). In essence, NFD and NFC are canonical equivalence while their K counterparts are about the weaker compatibility equivalence which include changing sub-script/super-script to regular characters (among other things). For example, 2<sup>5</sup> is encoded as 0032 2075 in NFD or NFC (where 2075 is 5 in super-script position), but it is 0032 0035 in NFKD or NFKC (where 0035 is the regular 5).